# Como gerar matrizes aleatórias sem números repetidos na mesma linha?

Tags: java, algoritmo, matriz, random

Quero armazenar números aleatórios de 1 a 60 em uma matriz. Quando houver números iguais nas linhas, é pra gerar outro número aleatório.

Tipo, não pode ser: 11 55 55 43 49 30, e sim deve ser 11 55 52 43 49 30. Não deve haver repetições.

Fiz esse código que gera normalmente, mas queria remover os números repetidos das linhas e colocar novos números que não são iguais.

```
package Tentativa;
import java.util.Random;
public class Loteria {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][]mega = new int[7][6];
        int[][]numero = new int[7][6];
        Random gerador = new Random();
        for(int x=0; x<7; x++) {
            for(int y=0; y<6; y++) {
                mega[x][y] = gerador.nextInt(60) + 1;
            }   
        }
        for(int x=0; x<7; x++) {
            for(int y=0; y<6; y++) {
                System.out.print(mega[x][y] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Só joga esse código no `main`:

```
int[][]mega = new int[7][6];
Random gerador = new Random();
for(int x=0; x<7; x++) {
    for(int y=0; y<6; y++) {
        int n = gerador.nextInt(60) + 1;
        int z = 0;
        while(z < 6){
            if(mega[x][z] == n){
                n = gerador.nextInt(60) + 1;    
                z = 0;
            }
            z++;
        }
        mega[x][y] = n;
    }   
}
for(int x=0; x<7; x++) {
    for(int y=0; y<6; y++) {
        System.out.print(mega[x][y] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Valeu cara. Eu queria desse jeito mesmo.

Answer (score 6):

Gere uma lista com todos os números possíveis, embaralhe eles e pega os 6 primeiros:

```
List<Integer> lista = new ArrayList<>(60);
for (int i = 1; i <= 60; i++) {
    lista.add(i);
}
Collections.shuffle(lista);
lista = lista.subList(0, 6);
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/TOzV9v). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/mrmqgwmc-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Collections/FisherYates.java).

Este algoritmo é o [Fisher–Yates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)

Comment: Só acrescentar um detalhe: ele está utilizando array.. então depois de gerar a lista precisa fazer um `lista.toArray()`

Comment: @PedroLaini é verdade, mas não sei se ele precisa e deveria usar o *array*.

Comment: Pois é. E tava vendo aqui: o `lista.toArray()` retorna um `Object[ ]` e não da pra converter para `int[ ]`... aí tem que iterar na lista e inserir os elementos 1 a 1 no array

Comment: @PedroLaini de qualquer forma ele quer a outra forma.

Answer (score 0):

Usando esse código os números não se repetem, pois é usado o `add()` e o `remove()`.

Segue o código:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;


public class Gerador {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


            Random rdn = new Random();
            List<Integer> numeros = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                numeros.add(i);
            String b = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                b += numeros.remove(rdn.nextInt(numeros.size()));
            }
            System.out.println(b);
```