# Como gerar numeros aleatorios em Java sem repetição?

Tags: java

Gostaria de saber como gerar números aleatório sem repetição estou tentando esse método mas me parece não está funcionando corretamente.

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> numerosAleatorios(int inicio, int fim, int quant)
    {

        // cria um objeto da classe Random
        Random rnd = new Random();

        // vamos preencher um ArrayList com a faixa de números
        ArrayList numeros = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = inicio; i < fim; i++)
        {
            numeros.add(i);
        }

        // vamos embaralhar o ArrayList
        for (int i = 0; i < numeros.size(); i++)
        {
            int a = rnd.nextInt(numeros.size());

           Object temp = numeros.get(i);
            numeros.set(i,numeros.get(a));
            numeros.set(a,temp);
        }

        // vamos obter as quantidade de
        // que queremos
        return (ArrayList<Integer>) numeros.subList(0, quant);
    }
```

Comment: Também tem essa: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39951/101

Comment: @bigown sua resposta solucionou meu problema http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/82819/como-gerar-matrizes-aleat%C3%B3rias-sem-n%C3%BAmeros-repetidos-na-mesma-linha